# Finding best neural network structure and inputs using optimization algorithm and cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, neural-networks, pattern-recognition

I'm using optimization algorithm to find best structure+inputs of a `patternnet` neural network in `MATLAB R2014a` using `10-fold cross validation`. Where should i initialize weights of my neural network?

```
*Position_1(rng,configure,randperm?)*

for i=1:number_of_loops

*Position_2(rng,configure,randperm?)* 
- repeating cross validation

for i=1:number_of_kfolds

*Position_3(rng,configure,randperm?)*
- Cross validation loop

end
 end
```

I'm repeating `5-fold cross validation` (because random selection of cross validation) to have more reliable outputs (average of neural network outputs). Which part is better for weight initialization for neural network (`Position_1`,`Position_2` or `Position_3`) and why?

There is a discussion here that may help :

[Classification+Optimization Mathworks community](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152947-finding-best-neural-network-structure-using-optimization-algorithms-and-cross-validation)

We should set `rng` function in a appropriate position to have unbiased designed and errors. Where is appropriate position for this function? As you know we are calling these codes as cost function of optimization algorithm that is searching for best neurons,layers and inputs combination so i think the logical solution is that we only should have one `rng` structure in all calling of cost function by optimization algorithm but with that we can't search all space (maybe some initial weights or indexes for train/test/validation are poor and we don't change it in all system. What is your recommendation based on the above link?

My revised solution is that have `rng` in position 1 and weight initialization (`configure`) in position 3. It is better than removing `rng` from all system but can optimization algorithm compare the cost functions because different random number generator of total cost calling (different weights and indexes of train/test/validation) but same random generator in every calling of cost function by optimization algorithm (cost function loops) ?

finally we will use all models from best cost function that will find by optimization algorithm as a pack (`number_of_loops*number_of_kfolds models`) and average between outputs for out-sample data so we are searching for best pack of models not only structures. What do you think about this?

** *So briefly we should set position of `configure` for neural network weight initialization, `rng` for random number generator (that we will save and restore it in every calling of cost function) and `index=randperm(number_of_samples)` for `cross validation` (after that we separate it to train/test/validation in inner loop).*

Comment: If your rng function does not initialize weights, what does it do?  You write "We should set rng function in a appropriate position to have unbiased designed and errors."  What are "unbiased designed and errors"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. it depends on position of `rng`. We can initialize indexes of `train/test/validation` or weights or both of them in these loops. We can have `rng` in position 2,save it and return the saved `rng` in every call of these codes by optimization algorithm so we have `number_of_loops=X` weights in every outer loop but these wights are from same saved distribution. The problem is this: we are comparing final output cost of these loops (average) in every calling of these codes by optimization algorithm so we are comparing different structures of neural networks.

Comment: If we don't set any `rng`, we have different initial weights and indexes for cross validation. Can we compare different structures of neural network and so final chosen models? ( we are using all `number_of_loops*number_of_kfolds` models as a black box and average between outputs of these best models (with lowest classification error)